# GeoServer: Problem rendering GeoTIFF

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff

I have a problem with the rendering of a GeoTIFF on GeoServer. This is a single image WMS request but this happens also on tiled requests.
Not every request produces this problem. Sometimes it loads fine, but I can't figure out the difference between the requests, beyond the bboxes.

[image: problematic rendering]

Some minutes later, for the same request:
[image]

**Source data**
An hillshade GeoTIFF, of 10m resolution and 35mb of total size on disk. Info from QGIS:

```
CRS EPSG:32626 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 26N - Projected
Extent  365536.2790999999851920,4248935.6501000002026558 : 410236.2790999999851920,4269055.6501000002026558
Unit    meters
Width   4470
Height  2012
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
```

**WMS request**

```
SERVICE: WMS
VERSION: 1.3.0
REQUEST: GetMap
FORMAT: image/png8
TRANSPARENT: true
LAYERS: context:hillshade_Azo_Pix
CRS: EPSG:3857
STYLES: 
WIDTH: 2505
HEIGHT: 1032
BBOX: -3202736.94991267,4622674.188938925,-3106999.571998813,4662115.695528585
```

**GeoServer**
Version 2.19.0, running on OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 16.
I've tried with and without `MarlinRenderingEngine` and results are the same.
There is little to no load on this system.

**Logging**
I also inspected the logs (default, geoserver_dev and geotools_dev profiles) and i can't see anything suspicious beyond this:

```
2021-05-08 18:54:18,312 WARN [lite.gridcoverage2d] - Could not reduce the grid geometry inside the valid area bounds: ReferencedEnvelope[-2.147483647E9 : 2.147483647E9, -85.0 : 85.0]
```

Comment: did you correctly set the SRS as 32626 in GeoServer?

Comment: Yep, i did @IanTurton